# C# JOIN and DataSet: how will it work?

Tags: c#, join, dataset

I have two tables: A and B.

*Table A*:

```
Id | Number
1  | 2
2  | 5
3  | 1
```

*Table B*:

```
Id | Name
2  | X
5  | Y
1  | Z
```

When I get information from the database, I populate a DataSet. However, I use JOIN on A.Number = B.Name. So resulting in:

**Result**:

```
Id | Number | Name
1  | 2      | X
2  | 5      | Y
3  | 1      | Z
```

I have a DataGridView which displays the **Result**, but only **Id** and **Name** columns.

One thing bothers me. I would want to change ***Result*.Name** value in the DataGridView, but I want *table A* to be updated with respective ***A*.Number** value for the ***B*.Name** value. *Table A* doesn't have **Name** column.

So I want to get things like this:

**Table A before**:

```
Id | Number
1  | 2
```

**Number** 2 accords to 'X' **Name** value.

Change **Name** in the DataGridView for 'Y' which accords to '5' **Number**...

**Table A after**:

```
Id | Number
1  | 5
```

Comment: From a relational database design point, such behaviour doesn't make sense. The thing to fix here is your database design, not the code.

Comment: Why do you think so? Say, I have a table which contains city Residents(Id, Surname, City) and a table with Cities(Id, Name). And so JOIN would look like Residents.City = Cities.Id. Pretty common design, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you are correct, but your approach to handle it is little clumsy :). Since my comment was to large I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Just new to Windows application design, been a web programmer for a while. Have you ever seen <select> HTML element? I want something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a Join.

You want to show table A as the principal with a lookup column for Number.

You'll need a Relation between A and B and an DataColumn with an [Expression property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on A

Answer (score 0):

I assume `Id` is a PK in both tables. By changing name of 'X' in `B` table you change `Name` value associated with `Id`=2. If you want to change associated value of `Id`=1 in table `A` you need to change it's `Number` value to 5, not, the `Name` itself.

That you asking is actually something like: "I want `Number` to change automatically to some other based on a Name (which is not unique) if it's exist in Table `B`". Thich is quite absurd to me. For example, what is value is changed to item not in the list?

That you need to is a some sort of Table `A` list with a DropDown for `Number` filled with values from Table `B`. Then users will select value from predefined list, and you update Table `A` with correct `Id`.

Comment: Yes, I use dropdown. I have "Accounts" table and "Companies". Relation is Account.Company = Companies.Id. In the DataGridView "Company" column for Accounts is dropdown, filled with names from "Companies" table.

Comment: Then I don't understand that seems to be a problem. Post the code part which causes difficulties.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't update the database with respective value. I've set proper ValueMember and DisplayMember. I change value in the DropDown, but the database remains unaltered. There is no code, it's all encapsulated in DataSet.

Comment: Now, after playing with values, I've managed to get it working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See also: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3805/Inserting-relational-data-using-DataSet-and-DataAd

Answer (score 0):

I would change the **Result.Name** column to a [`DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx), wire-up Table B to it, and reference the combo's value client-side before sending it back to the DB to store.

Here are the [other columns types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s.aspx) for `DataGridView`

- `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`
- `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`
- `DataGridViewImageColumn`
- `DataGridViewButtonColumn`
- `DataGridViewLinkColumn`
- *Custom:* inherit from `DataGridViewColumn`

Comment: Thanks, I already use DataGridViewComboBoxColumn which takes data from Table B. The only thing that bothers me is if I change that dropdown value, what is going to be saved to the database? Table B values or literal DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Value?

Comment: If you've done the binding correctly, Table B values should be `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Value`.

Comment: So, I've set the column from A to have DisplayMember = B.Name and ValueMember = B.Id. Is it what you mean?